# How to show image using ImageView in Android

Tags: android, imageview

I am looking for the way to assign image src to image view control. I read few example and they says something `src="@drawable\image"` but didn't understand this, also  I want to assign image src at runtime by java code also want to apply default image in XML.

Comment: Here http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Images-In-Android/ is a good tutorial.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If you want to display an image file on the phone, you can do this:

```
private ImageView mImageView;
mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewId);
mImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("pathToImageFile"));
```

If you want to display an image from your drawable resources, do this:

```
private ImageView mImageView;
mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewId);
mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageFileId);
```

You'll find the `drawable` folder(s) in the project `res` folder. You can put your image files there.

Comment: Thanks Michell, I created an Images folder in my project, inside of it there is a png image Black_x.png, So what should be the path here to decode image, it should be Images\Black_x.png ?

Comment: You should put your images in the drawable folder(s) in /res/. It'd be a good idea to use different sized images for each of the folders (i.e. hdpi and mdpi). Then use `setImageResource(R.drawable.black_x)`

Comment: Once again Thanks, but when I am using R.id.imageViewId here I am not getting any id option means when I type R.id it says id is invalid

Comment: I really don't know how to explain it otherwise, as it's quite simple. Put an image file in your /res/drawable/ folder (if there's no drawable folder, use drawable-mhdpi or similar). Android will automatically create a reference to that image with its filename as the ID - i.e. R.id.black_x if your image file is called "black_x.jpg".

Comment: @MichellBak and when does it create the ID file?

Comment: @MichellBak so XML file was the problem. Got it.

Answer (score 16):

You can set imageview in XML file like this :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/imagep1" />
```

and you can define image view in android java file like :

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewId);
```

and set Image with drawable like :

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageFileId);
```

and set image with your memory folder like :

```
File file = new File(SupportedClass.getString("pbg"));
if (file.exists()) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap selectDrawable = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(selectDrawable);
}
else
{
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File not Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In res folder select the XML file in which you want to view your images,

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/imagep1" />
```

Answer (score 2):

shoud be *@drawable/image* where *image* could have any extension like: *image.png*, *image.xml*, *image.gif*. Android will automatically create a reference in R class with its name, so you cannot have in any drawable folder image.png and image.gif.

Answer (score 1):

Drag image from your hard drive to Drawable folder in your project and in code use it like this:

```
ImageView image;

image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourimageviewid);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagename);
```