# Android Service, Keeping Track of Objects

Tags: android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver, pass-by-reference

This is kind of convoluted, so please bear with me. I have an object that has an ImageView instance variable. The image that I need to attach to the object is stored on a server, and will vary from instance to instance. Therefore, I need to get it dynamically.

Each object gets instantiated through the `onCreate()` method of a `ListActivity` class. To retrieve the appropriate image, right after instantiation, I have a service whose role is to download the correct image file from a server. It stores the image on the SD card. So far, so good. The file gets downloaded correctly.

Here is where I am stuck. When the service completes, I need to be able to link the object for which I was intending to get the file, to the file itself. To accomplish this, I was trying to pass along the object itself into the service and then back to the `BroadcastReceiver`. the problem with this approach, I have discovered, is that whenever I pass along the object, it gets passed by value, not by reference. Thus, a new object is created and the trail is destroyed.

I'm sure that this is confusing. Here is the relevant code. I can post more if it will help. I'm open to any ideas as to how to keep track of this object or to any better ideas as to how to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance. I know that this is strange question. I hope that I've explained it well enough.

From `onCreate()` in `ListActivity`:

```
//get the image for this workout type
System.err.println("workout: " + workout);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, DownloadPicture.class);
intent.putExtra("workout", workout);
intent.putExtra(DownloadPicture.FILENAME, filename);
startService(intent);
System.err.println("service started");
```

The service

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Workout callingObject = intent.getParcelableExtra("workout");
    System.err.println("onHandle workout: " + callingObject); //<--I can see that this is a different object by the pointer reference
    String fileName = intent.getStringExtra(FILENAME);
    String urlPath = this.getResources().getString(R.string.imagesURL) + fileName;
    //download the file...

private void publishResults(Workout callingObject, String fileName, String outputPath, int result) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(NOTIFICATION);
    intent.putExtra("workout", callingObject);
    intent.putExtra(FILENAME, fileName);
    intent.putExtra(FILEPATH, outputPath);
    intent.putExtra(RESULT, result);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
  }
```

And then back in the `ListActivity`, the `BroadcastReceiver`. This creates a null pointer error, since the object 'workout' is null (if it were passed by reference it would not be null):

```
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                Workout workout = bundle.getParcelable("workout");
                String filePath = bundle.getString(DownloadPicture.FILEPATH);
                int resultCode = bundle.getInt(DownloadPicture.RESULT);
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    System.err.println("Download done: " + filePath);
                    System.err.println(workout.getWorkoutType().getDescription());
                    workout.getWorkoutType().setPicture(filePath);
                    workoutsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();         
                } else {
                    System.err.println("Download failed");
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your `workout` objects are in an adapter. In this case you can use the `workout` object's index as the unique identifier.

Instead of the object itself, pass the object's index when you create the intent to send to the service. When the service publishes results, get the correct `workout` object from the adapter by the index that you passed when calling the service.

Comment: I'm almost there, but I can't quite get over the finish line. I have the position returned to the broadcast receiver, along with the file name. But now I still don't know how to make the adapter recognize this file and update the image. Can you post some code to help me? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what `workout.getWorkoutType()` returns, and what happens when you call `setPicture()`. But normally, the adapter would set the image when the item is being redrawn. Here is a good answer that shows how to set the picture in the `ImageView` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051069/how-to-show-image-using-imageview-in-android