# Posting image centered at given pixel coordinates

Tags: android, imageview

I am creating an activity which has got some blocks and when a user clicks on one of these blocks a image, which is saved in drawable folder, appears at the center of the clicked block.

So my main problem is how to paste or post the image which is centered at the coordinates which I can give as input.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an ImageView in blocks, place it and set hight / width values as you wish. Put image on ImageView by writing an onClick method for container or ImageView itself. Type of input (image source as i understand) is also important.

You can see some of the methods here:
[How to show image using ImageView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051069/how-to-show-image-using-imageview-in-android)

Comment: yeah thats what I was gonna do as last resort, being no alternative I think thats the only way. Thanks anyway.