# Trying to set an image in textView from in Strings.xml in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to set an image stored in assets folder in strings.xml and set that string to a TextView. Is this possible?

Strings.xml has the following string:

```
<string name="nofriends">No Friends.. <![CDATA[<br><br><br><br> <img src=\"file:///android_asset/sad.png\"/>]]></string>
```

And in my java file I am setting something like this"

```
Spanned text = Html.fromHtml(res.getString(R.string.nofriends));
noFriends.setText(text);
```

I am getting the text with a small green box but not the actual image?

Can anybody help me fix this?

Comment: textview is meant to have texts,you can use imageviews instead.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051069/how-to-show-image-using-imageview-in-android

Comment: set android:drawable left,right,bottom,top to show image with a text for textview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ImageGetter to get image from drawable resource.

```
ImageGetter imageGetter = new ImageGetter() {

    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourimage);
        d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
        return d;
    }
};

Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(
    "<img src='" + getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourimage) + "'/>", imageGetter, null);
```

now set it to TextView

```
textView.setText(spanned);
```

**Edit**

```
<string name="nofriends">No Friends.. ####</string> //#### to replace with image

String s=res.getString(R.string.nofriends);
s=s.replace("####",spanned);
textView.setText(s);
```

Comment: Great. Thanks @Ketab Ahir. With this and few changes to suit my project..solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

`TextView`'s are not designed to be used like this. What you should be doing instead is setting the drawable attribute on a `TextView`.

See a great answer to a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6932112/1082942).