# How do I use my ImageView?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, object

Sorry if this is a really basic question, but this is one of those times where I've just searched everywhere for multiple hours with no luck... So, I'm making a button with my own Button class, and I made it take in an image parameter:

```
public class Button{
    int xPos;
    int yPos;
    int width;
    int height;
    String name;

    // Constructor
    public Button(int x, int y, int w, int h, String n, ImageView t)
    {
        xPos = x;
        yPos = y;
        width = w;
        height = h;
        name = n;
    }
}
```

Now, I call it by creating its object (while putting it in an arraylist of buttons) like this:

```
greenView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.greencircle);
greenView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("@drawable/bluecircle"));

blueView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bluecircle);
blueView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("@drawable/bluecircle"));




ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
buttons.add(new Button(85, 184, 100, 100, "greencircle", greenView));
buttons.add(new Button(185, 184, 100, 100, "bluecircle", blueView));
```

Now the problem is, I am not able to do the `findViewById` for some reason. It sates that greencircle is not resolved, and neither is bluecircle. Now, I am making these images completely programmatically, with **no layout involved.**

I saw the answer to this question:

[How to show image using ImageView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051069/how-to-show-image-using-imageview-in-android)

Where my method **should** have worked. For some reason, I am not able to resolve the id. What should I do?

Thanks so much,

Ruchir

Comment: If you created the buttons programmatically, `findViewById()` wont work.

Comment: @LaneSurface What should I use instead to create my image view object?

Comment: Hmm, haven't done Android programming in a while, but I know that `findViewById()` is for finding views registered in your XML layout file

Comment: @LaneSurface Yeah, and that's what I thought too. But, that's what the answer on the link said, so how should I do it properly?

Comment: The code in the link is referencing an `ImageView` defined in the XML

Comment: @LaneSurface Oh, so what should I do to pass in the image? Thanks

Comment: Isn't there already a class called `ImageButton` that achieves your goal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96204/discussion-between-ruchir-baronia-and-lane-surface).

Answer (score 0):

Your button will not work. you have to import android button which is subclass of Viewgroup.

```
import android.widget.Button;


Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText("Button added dynamically!");
    b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    b.setId(MY_BUTTON);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);

ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
buttons.add(b);
```

Comment: See, I tried that before, but ran into this problem. The answer on the page and the comments on the answer explain it: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/111969/swap-buttons-in-layout/111970#111970

Answer (score 0):

Your program wont work until you set an id for the button. Since you are not using an xml layout you can set id in the program. 
You can manually set an id by
yourView.setId();
Hope this helps